# How to copy the contents of a html div from a website using Java

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to write a function in java that will basically copy and paste the html code from a div from a url. The data in question is from http://cdn.espn.com/sports/scores#completed however the data is not viewable when copied into my function using io streams. The data itsself is is viewable when I click inspect and control-f "completed-soccer" it shows up as  but my code does not retrieve it at all. Here is the code i used.

```
package project;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class DownloadPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Make a URL to the web page
        URL url = new URL("http://cdn.espn.com/sports/scores#completed-soccer");

        // Get the input stream through URL Connection
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is =con.getInputStream();


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;

        // read each line and write to System.out
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reach the data with normal HTTP request, you have to use more complex library, as Selenium with a Webdriver.

This library allows you to really navigate in a webpage, execute javascript and inspect all the element.

You can find a lot of information and guides.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://cdn.espn.com/sports/scores#completed-soccer");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try
        {
            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```